# Selenium Python -- How to render HTML element from string with inline styles

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

e.g., I want to render this table with python selenium.

```
<table border="1" style="margin:0.5em auto; font-size:95%;clear:both;"><thead><tr>
<th colspan="3" style="border-top: 5px solid #ccccff;">Political offices
</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr style="text-align:center;">
<td rowspan="1" style="width:30%;">Preceded by<div style="font-weight: bold">Position Created</div></td>
<td rowspan="1" style="width: 40%; text-align: center;"><b> President of Kabardino-Balkaria </b><br/>1992–2005</td>
<td rowspan="1" style="width: 30%; text-align: center;">Succeeded by<div style="font-weight: bold">Arsen Kanokov</div></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I could render it excluding styles with:

```
driver.get(
    "data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(
        html_content=urllib.parse.quote(html_table_string)
    )
)
```

And I also know that styles can be added using `driver.execute_script`. e.g.,

```
tables = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "table")
style_script = f"arguments[0].setAttribute('style','{table_style}')"
for table in tables:
    driver.execute_script(style_script, table)
```

But this would require me to first extract all styles from my original string, then add it back, which is a bit tedious (and hard). Is there a way to just render my original HTML string in seleniunm that includes styles?